# why an incidence example taken from literature doesn't work anymore?

Tags: r

I used this article to reproduce the plots. This worked in a very simple way.
Today I've tried to use the same code and this didn't work anymore and I don't know why...
I checked the code and it's ok...

code:

```
library('outbreaks')

dat1 <- ebola_sim_clean$linelist
str(dat1, strict.width = "cut", width = 76)

## 'data.frame':      5829 obs.  of  9 variables:
##  $ case_id                   : chr  "d1fafd" "53371b" "f5c3d8" "6c286a" ...
##  $ generation                : int  0 1 1 2 2 0 3 3 2 3 ...
##  $ date_of_infection         : Date, format: NA "2014-04-09" ...
##  $ date_of_onset             : Date, format: "2014-04-07" "2014-04-15" ...
##  $ date_of_hospitalisation   : Date, format: "2014-04-17" "2014-04-20" ...
##  $ date_of_outcome           : Date, format: "2014-04-19" NA ...
##  $ outcome                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Death","Recover": NA NA 2 ..
##  $ gender                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","m": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ..
##  $ hospital                  : Factor w/ 5 levels "Connaught Hospital",..: 2 ..

library('incidence')
library('ggplot2')

# compute weekly stratified incidence
i.7.group <- incidence(dat1$date_of_onset, interval = 7, groups = dat1$hospital)
# print incidence object
i.7.group

## <incidence object>
## [5829 cases from days 2014-04-07 to 2015-04-27]
## [5829 cases from ISO weeks 2014-W15 to 2015-W18]
## [6 groups: Connaught Hospital, Military Hospital, other,
##  Princess Christian Maternity Hospital (PCMH), Rokupa Hospital, NA]
##
## $counts: matrix with 56 rows and 6 columns
## $n: 5829 cases in total
## $dates: 56 dates marking the left-side of bins
## $interval: 7 days
## $timespan: 386 days
## $cumulative: FALSE

# plot incidence object
my_theme <- theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, color = "black"))

plot(i.7.group, border = "white") +
  my_theme +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.75))
```

the plot I should obtain
[image]

the plot I obtain:
[image]
the error message:

```
Warning message:
position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

I use ggplot2 version 3.3.0

What do you think?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Not able to reproduce as I was able to get the first plot with your code.  Can you try on a fresh R session.  Also, please post the package versions used

Comment: @akrun it would be helpful if you could tell which version of the package you are using. I think he update to a later version which is where the bug is residing.

Comment: it could be the reason. I have `packageVersion('ggplot2')#
[1] ‘3.2.0’`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some experiments with your code and I suspect most likely the error is due to a package update. I have noticed that the package treats your data differently depending on the size of the interval of days you choose.

When you execute this line

```
i.7.group <- incidence(dat1$date_of_onset, interval = 7, groups = dat1$hospital)
```

The y axis will be labeled: "ISO weekly incidence", which is also different from your example that worked.

Now if I change interval to 6 or 8, it will give a different label to the y axis, like: "Incidence by period of x days" and it will plot normally.

It seems like a new feature was added or changed to the package and it's not working well.

As a temporary fixup, until further debugging can be done (or maybe you downgrade your package), if that suits you, you can use an interval of 6 or 8 days. It will plot as expected.

Comment: Well, no feedback here